# Is it possible to run a windows service that sends emails on AppHarbor?

Tags: email, service, appharbor

Is AppHarbor only for website hosting, or is it possible to have a windows service run on it to send emails every day at X time. I have an email sending service that I want to integrate with my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppHarbor also supports [background workers](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/03/08/background-workers-in-beta) and using them to schedule tasks is [pretty simple](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/4/18/scheduled-tasks-using-quartz-and-appharbor-background-workers).

For sending emails, you should consider using one of the [email add-ons](https://appharbor.com/addons).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do the background workers come with the Catamaran pricing plan, or are they available in the free plan? Thanks.

Comment: Free plans only have one worker, and that can be either a web or a background worker.

Comment: I use quartz to make a worker but it stops working after some amount of time